Percentage probability with randomly chosen subjects
I have made a calculation in this problem which apparently is incorrect.Question :In a certain population of men, 5 percent of the men have coronary heart disease. A diagnostic test is used to indicate whether or not a man has the disease, but the test is not always correct.For men who have the disease,the test is correct 24 percent of the time, while for men who do not have the disease,the test is correct 98 percent of the time.If a man is randomly chosen from the population and the test indicates that he has the disease,then the probability that the test is correct is closest to which of the following: ( The answer is 39 %) .What I have done: 24/100 times 5/100 plus 98/100 times 95/100 equals 0.943 or about 94 percent, far from 39%....looks like this is conditional probability, and this time I get 24% ...still not correct??

Do you know what is a tree diagram for probability question?

Yes , but I cannot get the tree here

We write $D_M$ as the event that the man has the dieases and $D_T$ as the event that the machine shows the man has the dieases, similarly for $N_M$ and $N_T$. Then the given condition is same as \begin{align*}\mathbb{P}[D_M]&=0.05\\\mathbb{P}[D_T|D_M]&=0.24\\\mathbb{P}[N_T|N_M]&=0.98\end{align*}
Now we are going to find the probability that the test is correct given the machine shows that he has the diseases, equivalently, this is same as $\mathbb{P}[D_M|D_T]$. Now by Bayes theorem, we have $$\mathbb{P}[D_M|D_T]\mathbb{P}[D_T]=\mathbb{P}[D_T|D_M]\mathbb{P}[D_M]=0.24(0.05)=0.012$$
The only unknown we need to know other than the required term is $\mathbb{P}[D_T]$. By applying the given items we can see that $$\mathbb{P}[D_T]=\mathbb{P}[D_T\cap D_M]+\mathbb{P}[D_T\cap N_M]=0.012+\mathbb{P}[D_T\cap N_M]$$
Again we need $\mathbb{P}[D_T\cap N_M]$, but this is equal to $$\mathbb{P}[D_T\cap N_M]=\mathbb{P}[N_M]-\mathbb{P}
[N_T\cap N_M]=(1-0.05)-0.98(1-0.05)=0.019$$
Combining all the stuff gives $\mathbb{P}[D_M|D_T]=\dfrac{0.012}{0.012+0.019}=\dfrac{12}{31}\approx38.71\%.$

This is too hard , I thought I understood it but I don't.putting a bounty on it.

We want to determine the probability that a man actually has coronary heart disease given that his test result is positive for the disease.
In this population, 5% of men have coronary heart disease. If a man has the disease, the test correctly identifies this
% of the time. If a man does not have the disease, the test correctly indicates this 98% of the time, meaning it incorrectly identifies 2% of healthy men as having the disease.
To find the probability that a man has the disease given a positive test result, we first need to determine the overall frequency of positive test results and then the proportion of those results that are correct.
We can break this down into two groups: those who have the disease (5% of the population) and those who do not (95% of the population).

For the 5% of men who have the disease, the test will correctly identify 24% of them, which is 0.24 × 5% = 1.2% of all men.
For the 95% of men who do not have the disease, the test will incorrectly identify 2% of them as having the disease, which is 0.02 × 95% = 1.9% of all men.

Adding these, the total percentage of men who receive a positive test result is 1.2% + 1.9% = 3.1%.
Now, we calculate the probability that a man actually has the disease given that the test result is positive. This is the ratio of men who have the disease and receive a positive test result to the total number of positive test results:
$P(\text{Disease} \mid \text{Positive Test}) = \frac{P(\text{Positive Test} \mid \text{Disease}) \times P(\text{Disease})}{P(\text{Positive Test})} = \frac{1.2\%}{3.1\%} \approx 0.387$
Therefore, the probability that a man actually has coronary heart disease given that his test result is positive is approximately 38.7%.

Very grateful for your contribution Arjun.

A crosstabulation is often worth a dozen formulas, and problems like this are often easiest to solve numerically with a large $N$.
Suppose you test 1000 men for whom the probabilities given hold exactly. Fifty will have the disease (CHD) and 950 will not. Of the 50 with CHD, the test will be correct 24% of the time, so 12 will test positive and the other 38 will test negative. Of the 950 who do not have CHD, the test will be correct 98% of the time, so 931 will test negative and the other 19 will test positive. The exact numbers are shown in the table below.
Of the 31 men who test positive, 12 have CHD, which is ${12\over31} \approx 38.7\%.$

